# Python function to solve Ax = b by back substitution

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

Okay, for my numerical methods class I have the following question:

Write a Python function to solve Ax = b by back substitution, where A is an upper triangular nonsingular matrix. MATLAB code for this is on page 190 which you can use as a pseudocode guide if you wish. The function should take as input A and b and return x. Your function need not check that A is nonsingular. That is, assume that only nonsingular A will be passed to your function.

The MATLAB code that it refers to is:

```
x(n) = c(u)/U(n,n) 
for i = n-1 : -1 : 1
  x(i) = c(i);
  for j = i+1 : n 
    x(i) = x(i) - U(i,j)*x(j);
    end
  x(i) = x(i)/U(i,i);
end
```

My Python code, which I wrote using the MATLAB code snippet, is with an upper triangular test matrix(not sure if its nonsingular! How do I test for singularity?):

```
from scipy import mat
c=[3,2,1]
U=([[6,5,1],[0,1,7],[0,0,2]])
a=0
x=[]
while a<3:
    x.append(1)
    a=a+1

n=3
i=n-1
x[n-1]=c[n-1]/U[n-1][n-1]
while i>1: 
    x[i]=c[i]
    j=i+1
    while j<n-1:
        x[i]=x[i]-U[i][j]*x[j];
    x[i]=x[i]/U[i][i]
    i=i-1
print mat(x)
```

The answer I am getting is [[1 1 0]] for x. I not sure if I am doing this correctly. I assume it is wrong and can't figure out what to do next. Any clues?

Comment: I do not know what the output should be but matrix U multiplied by the output matrix should give me matrix c.

Comment: changing the i>=0: seems to give me an infinite loop.

Comment: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 2):

```
j=i+1
while j<n-1:
    x[i]=x[i]-U[i][j]*x[j];
```

is infinite ... and never gets executed

your indexing is fubared:

```
for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):
....
    for j in range(i+1,n):
```

notice, range is half open unlike matlab

Comment: How is it infinite when n is finite making the while condition legitimate?

Comment: neither `j` nor `n` change, so the truthiness of the statement never changes.

Comment: @aaa: yeah....noticed that after i wrote it. couldn't think of the word...truthfulness? isn't there a word for 'boolean value'?

Comment: @Mark heh, i am russian, dont know

Comment: Yup I should have not missed that. Then how could I properly translate the MATLAB code to python for my while statements?

Comment: @user use range instead, while sux imo

Comment: I am new to Python. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I was able to get it, forgot to update. Office hours really help sometimes. But still thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that your input consists of integers, which means that Python is going to do integer division on them, which will turn `3/4` into `0` when what you want is floating point division. You can tell python to do floating point division by default by adding

```
from __future__ import division
```

To the top of your code. From the use of scipy, I'm assuming you're using Python 2.x here.

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to test for singularity of an upper triangular matrix?

Please don't compute the determinant!

Simply look at the diagonal elements. Which ones are zero? Are any zero?

How about effective numerical singularity? Compare the smallest absolute value to the largest in absolute value. If that ratio is smaller than something on the order of eps, it is effectively singular.